# For loop issues with Quandl -- Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, for-loop, quandl

I'm trying to create a for-loop that automatically runs through my parsed list of NASDAQ stocks, and inserts their Quandl codes to then be retrieved from Quandl's database. essentially creating a large data set of stocks to perform data analysis on. My code "appears" right, but when I print the query it only prints 'GOOG/NASDAQ_Ticker' and nothing else. Any help and/or suggestions will be most appreciated.

```
import quandl
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

def nasdaq():
    nasdaq_list = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\NAME\Documents\DATASETS\NASDAQ.csv')
    nasdaq_list = nasdaq_list[[0]]
    print nasdaq_list

    for abbv in nasdaq_list:
        query = 'GOOG/NASDAQ_' + str(abbv)
        print query

    df = quandl.get(query, authtoken="authoken")
    print df.tail()[['Close', 'Volume']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating over a `pd.DataFrame` as you have done iterates *by column*. For example,

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape((3,3)))
>>> df 
   0  1  2
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8
>>> for i in df[[0]]: print(i)
0
```

I would just get the first column as a Series with [`.ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html),

```
>>> for i in df.ix[:,0]: print(i)
0
3
6
```

Note that in general if you want to iterate by row over a DataFrame you're looking for [`iterrows()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows).

Comment: Thank you. I was able to return the correct values.  :)